# Find the line index of the first line in a 2D array thjat is non full of NaN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2D array with plenty of lines fully fed with NaN values.
I would like to find where the first real number is present, i.e. the line number where it appears.
My simplified array looks like this:

```
m = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, 17, np.nan],[np.nan, 18, 25]])
```

The expected result is 2, the line number where 17 appears!
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the first row where at least one element is not nan using `sum` and `isnan`:

```
np.argmax((~np.isnan(m)).sum(axis=1) > 0)
```

### Edit

Based on I'mahdi's answer, I realize you can also just use `any`:

```
np.argmax((~np.isnan(m)).any(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.isnan()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and [`numpy.argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

```
m = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, 17, np.nan],[np.nan, 18, 25]])
r = np.argmax((~np.isnan(m)).any(1))
print(r)
# 2
```

If you want to find any indexes you can use [`numpy.argwhere()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) in this example if you want to find first and second:

```
np.argwhere((~np.isnan(m)).any(1))
# [[2] first is exist in index 2
#  [3] second is exist in index 3
# ]
```